# Printing output with comma separated values in a text file

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, tfs

I have a C# code to execute a TFS Shared query and loop through the result and print the result in a text file.

My Code is fetching back the results from the TFS shared Query and returning result, i want to print the defect id in a single line with comma separated. But my current code is printing each Id in each line.

```
Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>();
variables.Add("project", tfsQuery.Project.Name);
var results = witStore.Query(tfsQuery.QueryText, variables);


foreach (WorkItem item in results)
                {
                    var id = item.Id.ToString();
                    tw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", id));
                }
                tw.Close();
```

**For example:** if my result count is 5

**Expected:** 12345,23432,54654,23432,546542

**Actual:**

12345

23432

54654

23432

546542

Answer (score 1):

I have not used TFS, but try something like this:

```
var IDs = results.Select(w => w.Id.ToString());
tw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", IDs));
```

No loop needed.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are foreaching all the elements and for each element you are doing `tw.WriteLine()`. You have two options here either do `tw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", results.Select(w => w.Id.ToString()))` or you can use the foreach but do tw.Write() instead for example:

```
bool firstIteration = true;
foreach (WorkItem item in results)
{
   if(!firstIteration)
   {
       tw.WriteLine(",");
   }
   firstItreration = false;
   var id = item.Id.ToString();
   tw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
tw.Close();
```